# The correct classification of system costs: maintenance, excess consumption, necessary consumption, development?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics, labor-economics, economic-growth

Yesterday I saw in one of the videos on YouTube a classification of the expenses of the system consisting of:

- maintaining the system
- necessary consumption
- excess consumption
- development

Please tell me, do you know this classification? Who formulated and described it?

I want to find out if it is correct, because, in my opinion, it allows us to understand the basic functioning of systems